# PHP - array_push() & $array[] doesn't work?

Tags: php, arrays, push

### 1. PHP function.

I've created validating function, here it is in shorter version:

```
function my_function($input) {
   $settings = my_source(); // function taht outputs a long array

   foreach ($settings as $setting) {
      $id = $setting['id'];  
      $foo = $setting['foo'];
      $option = get_option('my_theme_settings');

        if($foo == "bar") {
           $valid_input[$id] = $input[$id];
        }  

   } 

   return $valid_input; 
};
```

Basically it takes $input and saves it as $valid_input. When it gets new $input it overwrites the old #valid_inpu and so on.

I want to create an additional $valid_input[$id] array that will not overwrite itself, but just push new elements inside.

### 2. Array_push() that doesn't work.

So the new updated code will look like that:

```
function my_function($input) {
   $settings = my_source(); // function taht outputs a long array

   foreach ($settings as $setting) {
      $id = $setting['id'];  
      $foo = $setting['foo'];
      $option = get_option('my_theme_settings');

        if($foo == "bar") {
           $valid_input[$id] = $input[$id];
        } 

        else if($foo == "noupdate") { // it doesn't work
           $valid_input[$id] = array();        
           array_push($valid_input[$id], $input[$id]);
        } 

   } 

   return $valid_input; 
};
```

As mentioned in comment above - this doesn't work, input always overwrites the option, it creates an array but it always contains only one element that is being erased with the new one (I guess array_push should prevent that behavior, right?).

### 3. The same happens with $array[] =

```
function my_function($input) {
   $settings = my_source(); // function taht outputs a long array

   foreach ($settings as $setting) {
      $id = $setting['id'];  
      $foo = $setting['foo'];
      $option = get_option('my_theme_settings');

        if($foo == "bar") {
           $valid_input[$id] = $input[$id];
        } 

        else if($foo == "noupdate") { // it doesn't work
           $valid_input[$id][] = $input[$id];
        } 

   } 

   return $valid_input; 
};
```

Still it overwrites the old value of $valid_input instead of pushing an element.

Any ideas? Maybe there's something wrong with the code? This whole function a Wordpress callback for function called [register_setting()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_setting), but I guess it's mostly PHP related as folks on WPSE can't help me.

### 4. EDIT

This does exactly what I want, but why point 3. doesn't work then?

```
    else if($foo == "noupdate") { // it doesn't work
       $valid_input[$id][] = 'something';
       $valid_input[$id][] = 'something_else';
       $valid_input[$id][] = 'something_else2';
    }
```

Comment: So you pass more than one `$setting` with the same `$id`. Have you tried debug-outputting `$id` and `$foo` inside the loop to check if it's not actually the data that leads to this behavior. I thought of a scenario where your `$valid_input[$id]` gets filled and the last `$setting` has `$foo == "bar"` and replaces your array with `$input[$id]`. Some example data for $settings would be helpful.

Comment: Basti, well, I guess something went really wrong since every setting has different $id :>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$valid_input[$id] needs to be set to array before you treat it as one.

```
$valid_input[$id] = array();
array_push(  $valid_input[$id], "some stuff");
```

Same deal with [] notation

```
$valid_input[$id] =  array();
$valid_input[$id][] =  "some stuff";
```

To check if the array has been declared, so this:

```
if(!is_array($valid_input[$id]){
   $valid_input[$id] =  array();
}
```

Comment: But I'm setting them as arrays, at least in the first example, it doesn't change anything in both cases.

Comment: You're trying to use them as multi dimensional arrays... the internal arrays are not being declared.  Try adding the array declaration before the push or assignment.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't exactly get what you mean. You are right, these are internal arrays, but I can't declare `$valid_input[$id]` as an array before foreach loop because it will create an array for all cases. And declaring it right before push/merging does nothing.

Comment: Ray, still nothing, but check the update. Maybe, just maybe, there's something wrong with $input[$id]?

Comment: That is the most ridiculous thing I've ever heard.
THANKS!

Comment: So it seems in php 7.2 i am required to define my array as an array first as this post outlines, in php 5.5 the following worked to add an array to multidimensional array $response_array['users'][] however in php 7.2 i must define $response_array['users'] as an array by $response_array['users'] = array(); before i can do $response_array['users'][] = array('id'=>'someID'); hope this helps someone as i fought for at least an hour trying to figure this out, until i found this post and tried setting as an array first

Comment: The second snippet is incorrect/misleading.  `$valid_input[$id] =  array();` is not necessary before pushing children into the parent with `$valid_input[$id][] =  "some stuff";` (square brace pushing syntax)

Answer (score 4):

The thing is that objects are passed as reference. you need to clone the objects before using the array_push function. here is a sample function that will clone an object:

```
function DeepCopy($ObjectToCopy) {
    return unserialize(serialize($ObjectToCopy));
}
```

then you can use it this way

```
array_push($MyObjectsArray, DeepCopy($MyObject));
```

Comment: `$valid_input[$id] = array_push($valid_input[$id],unserialize(serialize($input[$id])));` returns nothing.

Comment: @Wordpressor: You don't use `array_push()` like that - check the manual.  `array_push()` returns an integer value of the number of elements that are now in the array.  Doing it the way you did in your comment is just overwriting the array!

Comment: That did it! Thanks a lot! Although I just created a new object before assigning it and pushing it onto the array:     
    $dataObject = new $className;
    $dataObject = ...;
    array_push($dataArray, $dataObject);

Answer (score 1):

is it possible that you are trying to push a new value to the array with a key value that already exists?  i would test for an existing key value in your array before trying to push a value/key pair to it.  example:

```
if ( !isset( $arr[ $key ] ) ) {
  $arr[ $key ] = $value;
} else {
  echo " duplicate key value ";
}
```

Comment: b_dubb, nice try, but that's not the case :(

Comment: still i don't see that you are testing for an existing key element in your array.  you should test for that $arr[ key ] before trying to push new values to that $arr

Answer (score 0):

Either `array_push()` or a variable used with the array append operator `[]` need to actually be an array or these won't work.  Double check that whatever is in `$valid_input[$id]` is an array before doing array operations on the variable.  Check by doing:

```
if (is_array($valid_input[$id])) {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: Crontab, they're both arrays.